# How can I rewrite this nginx command with try_file in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want to hide jsp extension in url by Nginx. How can I rewrite this nginx command with try_file in Nginx?

```
location ~ .*\.jsp$ {
    root   /var/www/html/www.domain.com;
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.jsp?q=$1;
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~ \.jsp {
    try_files $uri /index.jsp?q=$request_uri;
}
```

http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil